# xamarin config file and sandbox

Tags: testing, xamarin, config, api-key

I have created a application and about to release in few days
After searching online I understand there is nothing like app.config for Xamarin.
Please suggest better place to save api keys

Also is there any environment where I can test my application before it goes live.
So I can see how it looks and functions in many devices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few options, for example:

1. Resource file (resx);
2. Constants file;
3. Api endpoint that retrieves config on startup. Huge benefit is that
   your config is dynamic. So if you change something in the config,
   it is automatically updated when user restarts the app.

For testing the app on multiple devices, try [TestCloud](http://testcloud.xamarin.com).

Comment: @SmallStep not everything is for free. You should put some effort into this. Basically what you need to do is:

1. Place a json file some where with your config stuff
2. On app startup retrieve the config file and update your config locally.

Please accept the answer if it helped you!

Comment: Thanks Mitchell, now I know what you exactly meant by point 3, but I don't agree with "not every things is free" . In .net we have app.config and web.config and we have config classes which helps us to add to and read from appsetting. But I might be wrong and happy to be corrected

Comment: I meant nothing is free by me giving you full source code before you tried to do it yourself! :-)

Comment: No problem! Could you accept the answer if it helped you. Goodluck!

Comment: I thought I already did , by clicking the up arrow!! I did it again

Comment: @SmallStep haha you need to click the tick icon, not the arrow :)